# Monitoring the number of threads running on kubernetes PODS

Tags: kubernetes

I have a use case where we need monitor the threads inside our pods, by using "kubectl top" i am able to monitor CPU, MEMORY.I am new to kubernetes and need to monitor the threads inside our pods.

```
NAME                   CPU(cores)   CPU%      MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
ip-XXX.ec2.internal    222m         11%       3237Mi          41%
ip-YYY.ec2.internal    91m          9%        2217Mi          60%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instrument your code using some standard library depending on the language the application is written and then you can expose the metrics at `/metrics` endpoint which can be scraped by prometheus and shown in a Grafana dashboard.

If it's a JVM based app then [micrometer](https://micrometer.io) is easy to use and exposes some metrics by default.

All other major languages has [prometheus client library](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/clientlibs/) which can used to instrument code and expose metrics.

Comment: We are having some JVM based app in our GKE development cluster. We are not using any monitoring tools. Can we implement a micrometer in our code and monitor application threads using Google Cloud Monitoring?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `Google Cloud Monitoring`. Micrometer supports stackdriver.Micrometer is a wrapper on prometheus client library. So if it does not work you can still use the client library directly.

Comment: Is there any way to see application threads in the Google Kubernetes Engine cluster without changing anything in the application end?

Comment: Without any change is not possible..if you don't want code change then try stack driver agent